# How to allow pgcli to show query result in prompt window, instead of editor?

Tags: postgresql, command-line-interface

pgcli is a command line tool, and I want it to show query result in prompt window. By default, it shows the result in an editor. How can I change the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the pager that psql invokes by default to display long result sets, it can be turned off.

Within the psql prompt :

```
\pset pager off
```

to configure the current psql session to always output results to stdout, as opposed to the default [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command))-like pager allocated to long results.

- cf. [psql
  documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html),
  entries `pager` and `pager_min_lines`
- cf. [this
  post](https://serverfault.com/questions/235184/turn-off-pager-for-psqls-interactive-output) with alternative syntaxes, and how to save the configuration system-wide

For the purpose of exploiting or transforming the result, I usually find it more convenient to invoke psql with -c and then pipe the output to an editor or whatnot : e.g. `psql -Atc 'select 1' | $EDITOR`